# JSP array output

Tags: arrays, jsp

How can I get the below output in jsp?

```
[[1417165200000,28477.92],[1417165320000,28484],[1417165440000,28474.86],[1417165560000,28478.88]]
```

Both the values comes from a variables in jsp code.

I have tried:

```
Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
list.put(last_traded_price, price_date);
```

It gives me this:

```
{28779.4400=2014-11-28 12:58:00.0, 28794.5000=2014-11-28 01:24:00.0}
```

Please suggest me what I can use in jsp to get the desired output.

This is what I did in php,

```
$array_item[] = array(strtotime($price_date)*1000, (float)$last_traded_price);
```

**Update 1:**

```
while(rs.next()){

last_traded_price = rs.getString(1);
price_date = rs.getString(2);

child.add(last_traded_price);//1
child.add(price_date);//2

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this `[[1417165200000,28477.92],[1417165320000,28484]]` particular format then i would advice you to use `json-simple.jar`
so if whenever you want to create data in above format you need to write code as below :

```
JSONArray root = new JSONArray();


while(rs.next()){
  JSONArray child= new JSONArray();
  last_traded_price = rs.getString(1);
  price_date = rs.getString(2);

  child.add(last_traded_price);//1
  child.add(price_date);//2
  root.add(child);
}
System.out.println(root);
```

so for `1417165200000,28477.92` this pair you will have root as `[[1417165200000,28477.92]]`

if you want to add another pair just repeat the  steps 1,2 and 3

Comment: I am getting this output `[["28477.9200","2014-11-28 09:00:00.0","28484.0000","2014-11-28 09:02:00.0"]]` updated my question with your suggestions.

Comment: convert values into their respective data types for eg `child.add(Double.parseDouble(oparr[i]));` when oparr is my string array.

you are storing strings that's why they are enclosed inside double quotes

Comment: No its not regarding the double quotes the brackets should close after each pair.

Comment: `JSONArray root = new JSONArray();

while(rs.next())
{
last_traded_price = rs.getString(1);
price_date = rs.getString(2);

child.add(last_traded_price));//1
child.add(price_date);//2
root.add(child);
}

System.out.println("Root = "+root);`

Comment: you forgot to create root array.add these child arrays in root array as shown above . Required data format is stored in root array.

Comment: Already tried this this goes to infinite loading. I have created `JSONArray root = new JSONArray();` just forgot to post it

Comment: please check my updated answer according to your requirements.

Comment: Update: Actually not going in infinite loop but some weird output, values getting repeated or something.

Comment: can you post what output you are getting ??

Comment: Tried every possible thing but cant get rid of " in output for date `[["2014-11-28 09:00:00 AM UTC", 28477.92], ["2014-11-28 09:02:00 AM UTC", 28484]]`

Comment: did you convert price_date string to date object ?? if you stored date object quotation issue will also resolved.if possible post your current code